# Adding a string to the Windows clipboard without adding it to the history in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, clipboard

I am using PowerShell to copy sensitive information to the Windows clipboard.

Since Windows 10 Vs. 1809 we have the enhanced clipboard with a history function. I don't want to have my sensitive information in the history.

The `Set-Clipboard` cmdlet doesn't have any helpful parameters. Even in C# I doesn't seem to have an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you can access the `Universal Windows Platform` (UWP) APIs directly in PowerShell:

```
 Function Set-ClipboardWithoutHistory([string]$Value)
 {
     [int]$RequestedOperationCopy = 1

     $null = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackage,Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
     $null = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ClipboardContentOptions,Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
     $null = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard,Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]

     $dataPackage = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackage]::new()

     $cOptions = [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ClipboardContentOptions]::new()
     $cOptions.IsAllowedInHistory = $false
     $cOptions.IsRoamable = $false

     $dataPackage.RequestedOperation = $RequestedOperationCopy
     $dataPackage.SetText($Value)

     [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard]::SetContentWithOptions($dataPackage, $cOptions) | Out-Null
 }
```

Comment: This is great! Do you also know how to use the [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard]::add_ContentChanged in PowerShell?

Comment: @Yiping - sorry, no idea. Would need to research that.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2019, PowerShell is still not able to naively prevent adding a new clipboard item to the clipboard history.

The APIs to do this are available for the `Universal Windows Platform` (UWP).

During 2019 Microsoft made it much easier to access certain APIs in UWP from Windows Desktop Apps, and as it turns out from PowerShell.

So I wrote a [small .Net assembly](https://github.com/hahndorf/ClipboardHelper) that I can use in PowerShell to prevent the usage of the history feature when copying text to the Windows clipboard.

The trick is to use:

> Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts

to access the UWP APIs, then use:

```
using uwp = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

  uwp.DataPackage dataPackage = new uwp.DataPackage { RequestedOperation = uwp.DataPackageOperation.Copy };
  dataPackage.SetText("text to copy");
  uwp.Clipboard.SetContentWithOptions(dataPackage, new uwp.ClipboardContentOptions() { IsAllowedInHistory = false, IsRoamable = false });
  uwp.Clipboard.Flush();
```